# Resetting template driven forms in angular 2 (models and validations both)

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

How do we reset the controls with validation states of **Template driven** forms in angular 2?
I know that controls can be reset by setting model values to which they are bound to. But what about the validation states(pristine, dirty etc..)?

I tried something like this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(playlistForm)" #playlistForm="ngForm">
// Some code here...
</form>
```

And in controller,

```
onSubmit(playlistForm: any) {
// ...
  playlistForm.form.reset();
}
```

But in above seems to actually redirect to the `''`
And I get error below:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ''
```

So how do I do what I want?

Answer (score 15):

Both of these worked for me:

```
playlistForm.reset();
playlistForm.resetForm(); // I think this is the one to use
```

Angular docs have resetForm() only
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgForm-directive.html

Comment: @StepanZarubin I'm using `angular 2.4.0` none of them works form me

Comment: reset() works for me in `Angular 6.1.0` from a FromControl class

Comment: reset() throws validation error after submit. What should i do?

Answer (score 4):

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(playlistForm)" #playlistForm="ngForm">
// Some code here...
</form>


onSubmit(playlistForm: ngForm) {
// ...
  playlistForm.form.reset();
}
```

Comment: typo >> onSubmit(playlistForm: NgForm) {

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(playlistForm);playlistForm.reset()" #playlistForm="ngForm">
    // Some code here...
</form>
```

Comment: `reset()` throws validation error after submit. What should i do?

Answer (score 3):

```
form.resetForm();
```

This also resets the validation states of the form, unlike `form.reset()`. Works with template-driven and reactive approaches.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a function anymore.

Comment: It is. I was using `@angular/forms: 8.0.0` when this answer was posted. I'm using `@angular/forms: 11.2.11` and `form.resetForm()` is currently available as a method in the class NgForm in the stated versions and the versions in between as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I used native element reference in .ts and called form later cleared the form data once submitted using reset method

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me onClear() is additional callback I needed for some additional tasks.

```
<button type="reset" (click)="onClear()">Clear</button>
```

Comment: This does not help OP. He is asking for clearing form when user click submit.